# Updating the value of a RatingBar using Calabash

Tags: android, ruby, calabash

I have been trying Calabash lately and it's pretty awesome! (although it could use some documentations). I have tried using this code

```
query("RatingBar index:1", setRating:3)
```

but it just returns

```
[
    [0] nil
]
```

Is there a way to do this at the moment? I know that with Robotium I have to use

```
solo.setProgressBar(1, 3);
```

But I don't see any equivalent for that here...

Any thoughts?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Please see my answer on the issue you created on GitHub: https://github.com/calabash/calabash-android/issues/324